# Is there any way to convert FilePart to File before saving to disk in Spring WebFlux?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, kotlin, spring-webflux

Suppose we have spring webflux controller like this that accepts image as FilePart, is there any way to convert FilePart to File (later convert to BufferedImage, to check resolution also) to check file size and other attributes when accept FilePart in Spring WebFlux before actually saving it on disk? how to get File from this class org.springframework.http.codec.multipart.FilePart ?

```
@PostMapping("file/single")
fun upload1( @RequestPart("image") image: FilePart): Mono<Void> {
    //convert FilePart to file, validate file size before saving 
//it?? then convert to BufferedImage and check resolution and other 
//attributes, header Content-length doesn't work every time
    return image.transferTo(paths.STORAGE_PATH.resolve(image.filename()))
}
```

Comment: Why doesn't `Content-length` work? Does it throw an exception?

Comment: it returns -1 in some cases

Comment: Try to specify that the controller accepts `MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA` and instead of `FilePart`  use `Part`? Maybe then you will always get `Content-Length`

Comment: anyway i need to get File from FilePart or Part, to check size, name and then to convert to image to do some other validations

Comment: Check this [here](https://ozenero.com/kotlin-springboot-upload-download-file-multipartfile-thymeleaf-bootstrap-4), I think it will help you.

Comment: the reason i asked this question is that it's easy to implement using MultiPart from spring-web, but i'm using spring-webflux, which doesn't support Multipart class, and uses FilePart instead

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238215/discussion-between-vova-backend-dev-and-aris).